# Kenlm library not found

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to install wav2letter from Facebook to Ubuntu 18.04. For this purpose I built kenlm and set KENLM_ROOT_DIR to it's directory as recommended in installation guide. But when I'm trying to build wav2letter I get next error:

CMake Error at cmake/Findkenlm.cmake:47 (message):
  kenlm library not found; please set CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH or KENLM_LIB

I also tried to set CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH and KENLM_LIB, edit ~/.bashrc like this:

export PATH=/mnt/data/repositories/src/kenlm/build:$PATH
export KENLM_ROOT_DIR=/mnt/data/repositories/src/kenlm/build
export CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=/mnt/data/repositories/src/kenlm/build

But error doesn't disappear. Also I realized that kenlm/build/lib directory is empty. Is it wrong and is someone know how to resolve error with "kenlm library not found"?